# How to make a git pre-commit hook that checks the commit message?

Tags: bash, git, githooks, git-commit

I have a git commit hook script, that checks the commit message, and if the message does not contain the word "updated", the script should reject the commit.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a commit message: " message

if [[ ${message} != *"updated"* ]];then
  echo "Your commit message must contain the word 'updated'"
  else
  git commit -m "$message"
  fi
```

How to make this hook automatically execute if I try to push some files in my local repo using the command

```
git commit -m "updated:something"
```

My idea is to make it not like "run this script to do commit", but rather when you open the console and try to make a commit and entering the commit message, the script will check your commit message automatically and pass it or reject it.

Comment: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit, or https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg, or https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_commit_msg.

Comment: thanks for reply! maybe you know how i can change my hook code , to reject commit if my message is not contain word "updated" ? for example if i type wrong message in git commit -m , it will be reject commit , if true pass it

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Taking `commit-msg` for example.

```
#!/bin/bash

MSG="$1"

if ! grep -qE "updated" "$MSG";then
    cat "$MSG"
    echo "Your commit message must contain the word 'updated'"
    exit 1
fi
```

`chmod 755 commit-msg` and copy it as `.git/hooks/commit-msg`.

Comment: can you please explain last line ? chmod 755 commit-msg and copy it as .git/hooks/commit-msg.  you mean chmod +x ./commit-msg ? what 755 is do ?

Comment: now i copy your code ant add it on file and then i  try commit i have an error : error: cannot run .git/hooks/pre-commit: No such file or directory

Comment: @Andrej `755` is an alternative of `a+x` here though they are not exactly the same. The last line `chmod ...` is not part of the hook `commit-msg`. Copy the code into a file and name the file `commit-msg`, make it executable and copy it to the current repository's `.git/hooks/`. When `git commit` is done, the hook `commit-msg` is invoked and checks the commit message. If it does not contain "updated", the commit fails.

Comment: I think this should be used chmod +x .git/hooks/commit-msg

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `[[ $(cat $1) =~ updated ]] || exit 1`

Comment: thank you! this works and isn't half as convoluted as other guides I have had the bad luck to find on the internet

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**commitlint**](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/#what-is-commitlint) with git pre-commit hook.

The simplest way I found to use it is via [pre-commit framework](https://pre-commit.com/).
The nice thing is that you can easily add and customize any other check before commiting, [here's a list of supported hooks](https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html).

#### Adding `commitlint` with `pre-commit`

`pip install pre-commit`
or `brew install pre-commit`

Create your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` (check and update rev if needed):

```
repos:
- repo: https://github.com/alessandrojcm/commitlint-pre-commit-hook
  rev: v2.3.0
  hooks:
      - id: commitlint
        stages: [commit-msg]
        additional_dependencies: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']
        args: ["--config",".commitlintrc.yaml"]
```

You have a lot of options with a commitlint configuration file `.commitlintrc.yaml`:

```
rules:
  body-leading-blank: [1, always]
  body-max-line-length: [2, always, 100]
  footer-leading-blank: [1, always]
  footer-max-line-length: [2, always, 100]
  header-max-length: [2, always, 100]
  subject-case:
    - 2
    - never
    - [sentence-case, start-case, pascal-case, upper-case]
  subject-empty: [2, never]
  subject-full-stop: [2, never, "."]
  type-case: [2, always, lower-case]
  type-empty: [2, never]
  type-enum:
    - 2
    - always
    - [build, chore, ci, docs, feat, fix, perf, refactor, revert, style, test]
```

Install commit message hook
`pre-commit install --hook-type commit-msg`

And then you can try to `git commit`.

You can also install commitlint directly via npm, here's how.

```
# Install commitlint cli and conventional config
npm install --save-dev @commitlint/{config-conventional,cli}

# Configure commitlint to use conventional config
echo "module.exports = {extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional']}" > commitlint.config.js
```

I recommend [Conventional Commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) format.

The commit message should be structured as follows:

```
<type>[optional scope]: <description>

[optional body]

[optional footer(s)]
```

Default types:
`build, chore, ci, docs, feat, fix, perf, refactor, revert, style, test`

Examples:

- `feat(parser): add ability to parse arrays`
- `docs: correct spelling of CHANGELOG`
- `ci: add docker build`

Some benefits of using this structure:

- Automatically generating CHANGELOGs.
- Automatically determining a semantic version bump (based on the types of commits landed).
- Communicating the nature of changes to teammates, the public, and other stakeholders.