# Making git produce a warning if no task was mentioned

Tags: git

I always forget to put the `#ID` in the commit message which is very bad for other people who are watching the issue.

Is it possible to force git to produce a warning telling me that I am trying to make commit without putting `#ID` in the commit message?

If not, can I do it on the git client level (such as SourceTree) ?

Comment: You can even abort commit if the message is wrong. You need a hook, `pre-commit` hook or `commit-msg`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45416049/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the ticket number in your branch names as well, you can do this in the `prepare-commit-msg` hook and include some basic handling logic to attempt to fix things if you forget to include the ticket id.

I use this script to grab the ticket number from the branch name and prepend it:

```
# Identify the task from the branch name if available
task=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD | grep -oP "TASK-\d+") 2>/dev/null

# If there is an error in symbolic-ref grab, you're on a detatched
# head, I've never run into this unless I was mid-rebase
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Head detatched, skipping commit message test"
else
    # Only process if the commit source is message
    if [ -v $2 ] || [ "$2" == "message" ]; then
        # Detect the task in the provided message
        hastask=$(head -1 $1 | grep -oP "TASK-\d+" | wc -l)

        # If the task was not found
        if [ "$hastask" == "0" ]; then
            # Prepend the task if found in branch name
            echo -e "Prepending task number\n\n"
            if [ -n "$task" ]; then
                echo -e "task Number resolved to $task\n"
                echo -e "$task: `cat $1`" > $1
            # Otherwise, notify the user and hault the commit
            else
                echo -e "task number not found in branch name\n\n"
                exit 1;
            fi
        # If you remembered to include a task, notify the user and do nothing
        else
            echo -e "task number already exists in message\n\n"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

If you're in charge of the server, you can follow this up with a check of all pushed commits in the `pre-receive` hook on the server to be extra safe.